# Unable to make clickable link in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I want to have a clickable uitextview hyperlink in iOS Swift 3. My Code:

```
private func setUpTextViews() {
  let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "http://www.vitensenteret.no")
  attributedString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "http//:www.vitensenteret.no", range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 19))

  hyperLink.attributedText = attributedString
  hyperLink.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.all
  phoneNumber.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.all
}

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in     characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
  UIApplication.shared.open(URL, options: [:])
  return false
}
```

Comment: Did you actually set your `UITextViewDelegate`?

Answer (score 1):

Is it because there is a typo in your link string?

```
"http//:www.vitensenteret.no"
```

Note the location of the `:`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled all below items inside storyboard to define on UITextView to act as link:

[image]

1. Uncheck editable,
2. Check Link for storyboard,
3. Make sure you have give delegate for UITextView to get call back for below delegate method:

   ```
   func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool
   {
   return true; 
   }
   ```

Also remove the ':' from above url given i.e., http://www.vitensenteret.no

Hope this will work for above issue.

Comment: note: `http//www.vitensenteret.no` is not a valid url - change it to `http://www.vitensenteret.no`